# How to decode html tags in xml using php

Tags: php, html, xml

I have tried to decode html tags in xml but the functions of the html tags was not worked.
Here is my code:

```
<?php

$sample = '<p>&nbsp Sample</p>
           <p>Sample 2</p>';

header('Content-type: text/xml');
$output = '<rss version="2.0">';
$output .= '<channel>';
$output = '<description>.utf8_encode(html_entity_decode($sample)).</description>';
echo($output);
$output .= '</channel>';
$output .= '</rss>';
?>
```

The output was a plain text. The function of `<p>` tag was not working. and when I remove `utf8_encode` it error the `&nbsp;`.

Comment: `&nbsp` is an invalid entity. You are outputting before closing the `channel` and `rss` elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
$sample = '<p>Sample</p><p>Sample 2</p>';

header('Content-type: text/xml');
$output = '<rss version="2.0">';
$output .= '<channel>';
$output .= '<description>'. strip_tags(utf8_encode(html_entity_decode($sample))).'</description>';
$output .= '</channel>';
$output .= '</rss>';
echo($output);
```

---

Result:

```
<rss version="2.0">
    <channel>
        <description>
            <p>Sample</p>
            <p>Sample 2</p>
        </description>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

---

you need to seperate PHP function on string.

Comment: Also you probably don't want to do a direct assignment to $output in the <description>... line. you probably want to use .= again

Comment: Sorry . I encode my code incorrectly . I use that code but i has the same output. The description was display a plain text.

Comment: @ChristianBeltran you have to strip tags you dont want

Comment: @JosuaMarcelChrisano same output when i use strip_tags.